# Types that can only be achieved via a type guard?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to enforce type safety on strings that are too complex for a template literal by using a regex type guard instead. This is a model of what I have:

```
type Foo = string;
function isFoo(str: string): str is Foo {
    return /.../.test(str);
}
function useFoo(foo: Foo) {...}
```

The problem is that plain strings can be passed to useFoo. I know I can just call isFoo inside useFoo and handle mismatches somehow, but it seems like it should be possible to tell Typescript that a type T can be used as a U but can only become a T through a type guard. I've tried looking for something like that but without formal names it's hard to search for something this specific. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, TypeScript does [*structural typing*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), so when you do `type Foo = string`, `Foo` and `string` can be used interchangeably.

But there is still a possibility to achieve your objective, by using a technique called "[branding](https://medium.com/@KevinBGreene/surviving-the-typescript-ecosystem-branding-and-type-tagging-6cf6e516523d)" (or "tagging").

E.g. with the [ts-brand](https://github.com/kourge/ts-brand) library:

```
import { Brand } from 'ts-brand';

type Foo2 = Brand<string, "Foo2">
function isFoo2(str: string): str is Foo2 {
    return /.../.test(str);
}
function useFoo2(foo: Foo2) { }

// Fail on string as expected
useFoo2("bar"); // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ __type__: "Foo2"; }'.

declare const foo2: string | Foo2;
// Fail on string | Foo2 as expected
useFoo2(foo2); // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ __type__: "Foo2"; }'.

if (isFoo2(foo2)) {
    // Okay on Foo2 only (e.g. here after type guard)
    useFoo2(foo2); // Okay!
    //      ^? Foo2
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgISgQwHYBM4F84BmUEIcA5DAM4C0ARutmQNwBQLMAnmAKZwBiECHAC8cSjCjAMAc1YEArhgDGMYBAxxglARAAU4qAC4xEqdICUxg5sr9BiFnCdwo3GPKgaA9ADo-vmG5xfQlzVlwWBWVVdTh5Sm4dXQJBYx1zRDw2eMTBXQAiWjQofLC4Ly84AHUIeQAbHDrgAGteGCECNGA6vx82Th47CAAmERQGLAAeAzMAGjh8nWH8gD5IxRU1DS0lkKMTSRlLA5sh0YRHZ1d3T3LegKCYPbCWCKjN2JzdlIg0wWGMkgIiwKvwunU4LEZjI4GhbNwAB48FTcLAsL7-ApFEplUEAUSgxH2ABUuLwyNDpGRThgIPA4ZRgNIMGhaHU2kIBuSkAB9HlcvnGRb-fJMPBkPosLDcJR1Yq8JTqcSEf5WUwwgA+Z1YoL44MhGkpcC1S1h8KRMsCaIxI2S-1xlQJROMpMGFPVVJpdLNjOZrPZcHagbJ5F5-LJgoWS1F4slwAIcF0O0xPwBgMuTlBAHlmmgOAazga6vndNwfNIfHAABbcVywgiBKDBwbSeTFLDmDNxBLfe1i7O5jgAQi7oOcTgAegB+V4sIA)

Answer (score 0):

That's seems to be a use case for a branded type : use an intersectionnal type too add  contraint ! Therefore bare strings won't be able to be used !

```
type Foo = string & { __brand: 'Foo' } ;
```

There a [complete example on the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?q=332#example/nominal-typing)